# HTML concatenation in js failed

Tags: javascript, html

```
  html += '<div style="background: url("http://graph.facebook.com/' + photo 
    + '/picture?type=normal") background-size: cover;>';
```

I've been trying for 1 hour still couldn't get it done right.

Comment: Have you declared the HTML variable before you started appending to it? Try this just above your code example `var html = '';`.

Comment: Please show us more code above this line

Comment: Updating a variable won't update what is actually displayed on the page, you'd have to have `someElement.innerHTML = html;`

Comment: @alexpls yes, this is the only line that caused problem. missing double or single quote

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because the quotes are not correct. You have nested double quotes which is causing a problem.

Your string looks like this when it is generated

```
<div style="background: url("http://graph.facebook.com/xxx/picture?type=normal") background-size: cover;">
```

The browser will see

```
<div style="background: url("
```

So you need to escape the quotes.

```
html += '<div style=\'background: url("http://graph.facebook.com/' + this.cover_photo 
    + '/picture?type=normal") background-size: cover;\'>';
```

Comment: can post better answer? where?

Comment: Yes, of course. The updated version of your answer is good. (I've forgotten now what your original wording was, but at the time I didn't think it adequately answered a question that complained about "concatenation" since the problem wasn't actually with the concatenation. I'll delete that comment.) And @UselessCode - *definitely* incorrect. Single quotes are valid even in XHTML.

Comment: @epascarello Hmmm... It seems you are [correct](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2). I could have sworn the in the past when I accidentally used a single quote the W3C validator got angry at me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to break it down.  What would you expect this to return when concatenated?  Substitute a value for `this.cover_photo`.  For example, assume `this.cover_photo` is `'foo'`

This would evaluate to:

```
<div style="background: url("http://graph.facebook.com/' + 'foo' + '/picture?type=normal") background-size: cover;>
```

Which would evaluate to:

```
<div style="background: url("http://graph.facebook.com/foo/picture?type=normal") background-size: cover;>
```

Your quotation marks are off, as you can see illustrated with StackOverflow's syntax highlighting above.  You need to either escape your inner quotes, or use no quotes at all for the `url`

Answer (score 0):

```
function templete_render(html, cover_photo){

   return html  + "<div style='background : url(http://graph.facebook.com/" + cover_photo + "/picture?type=normal) background-size: cover;'>";

} // end of templete_render
```

use :-

```
html = templete_render(html, this.cover_photo);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: This isn't quite right: the `style` attribute has two CSS properties in it but you've ended the attribute after the first one.

Comment: Can't you add those 2 properties before background :p ?  like :-    <div style="color : red; font-size : 15px; background : url(...)"> </div> ?

Comment: Huh? Just move the closing `'` to after the `background-size`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like that way. Its working fine.
Replace your code with this code:

```
html += '<div style="background: url(http://graph.facebook.com/' +photo+ '/picture?type=normal); background-size: cover;">';
```